# Can't access HDD partition with important files after trying to install ubuntu on another partition of the same disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I really hope someone can help me out.
I created a 300gb partition on my 1tb D: HDD using windows disk manager to install ubuntu there.
After selecting that partition in ubuntu installation for the ext4 / the installation failed.
I booted windows and the entire disk is gone. In disk manager it says Disk 0 Dynamic Invalid.
Is there a way to retrieve my files in the other partition I did not select?
If I convert back to basic it says I'll lose all my files.

Comment: Dynamic partitions are a proprietary Microsoft partitioning. If that is what you had, you could not convert one partition and install Ubuntu. Microsoft's official policy is a full backup, erase dynamic partitions and create new basic partitions. There is no undo.  The Ubuntu installer should have given you some info or warnings, but with gpt used since 2012 there is no need for dynamic partitions. It was another work around for the old MBR(msdos) 4 primary partition limit. You need to ask on a Windows forum, if there are any tools to recover from dynamic partitions.